# Image fade-in on scroll working for some images but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a page with multiple images on it and I will be adding more, I need the images to fade in as you scroll to them, preferable starting to fade in as you get half way down the image.

First here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $(".image").fadeTo(0, 0.0);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        container.each(function(i) {

            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var viewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewBottom = viewTop + windowHeight;

            var distanceFromTop = $(this).offset().top - viewTop;
            var distanceFromBottom = viewBottom - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height();

            var visible = (distanceFromTop + distanceFromBottom) <= windowHeight;
            var allVisible = (distanceFromTop * distanceFromBottom) >= 0;

            if (visible) {
                if (allVisible) {
                    $(this).stop().delay(0).fadeTo(1000, 0.99);
                } 
                else {
                    //$(this).stop().delay(0).fadeTo(1000, 0.0);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My first problem is that, the third image is not fading-in, sometimes it will, but most of the time it doesn't. The second problem is that I would like the images to fade-in as you get half way down the image, at the moment they fade in when you hit the bottom.

Edit: Forgot to include the demo: http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, I have included a link to a demo.

Comment: third image source is blank.. 
<img id="tablet-camera" class="image" src="" style="opacity: 0.99;">

Comment: That's odd, this is what I have in the html - <img src="images/tablet-ports.png" class="image" />